# TensorFlow is not using GPU despite all prerequisites installed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed CUDA 11.0, cuDNN 8.0.5 (for CUDA 11.0) and tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1. under Windows 10 Pro.
I am checking the installation using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(tf.version)
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print()
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
print()
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

The output seems to suggest that TensorFlow sees the GPU:

> <module 'tensorflow._api.v2.version' from
> 'C:\Users\Meir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\version\**init**.py'>
>
> True
>
> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
>
> PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
>
> [name: "/device:CPU:0" device_type: "CPU" memory_limit: 268435456
> locality { } incarnation: 2790105922589511936 , name: "/device:GPU:0"
> device_type: "GPU" memory_limit: 3173331764 locality {   bus_id: 1
> links {   } } incarnation: 12842674850440179486 physical_device_desc:
> "device: 0, name: NVIDIA Quadro M1200, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0,
> compute capability: 5.0" ]

The relevant entries in `PATH`:

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin
>
> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64
>
> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include
>
> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\libnvvp

Here is the `CUDA_PATH` (though probably unnecessary, since I copied .dll, .h and .lib files of cuDNN into the corresponding directories of CUDA):

> C:\cudnn-11.0-windows-x64-v8.0.5.39\cuda\bin

However, when I train a convolutional NN, CPU load rockets to almost 100% while GPU load remains at 0%.
What do I need to do to make TensorFlow use the GPU?

**Update:**
I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

for i in range(100):
    a = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1000, 1000))
    b = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1000, 1000))
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
    print(c[465][266])
```

The output (shown partially) says clearly that TensorFlow believes it is using the GPU:

> Executing op MatMul in device
>
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op StridedSlice
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
>
> StridedSlice in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
> tf.Tensor(48.741279799952544, shape=(), dtype=float64)

Still, `NZXT Cam` shows only CPU usage. It does show GPU utilization when I use `Zoom` though, so it is not a problem with `NZXT Cam`. It seems like TensorFlow thinks that it is using GPU while it is not doing so in reality...

Comment: Did you execute everything in https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows-cuda-cudnn/ here?

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu I used other sources, but yes, I think I did everything. In addition, part of the listed code is exactly the verification they suggest.

Comment: Okay,  it shows GPU anyway. Probably nothing wrong there. I check that your GPU is cuda compatible. So, maybe environment variables?

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu I followed the instructions. Both `PATH` and `CUDA_PATH` are set.

Comment: You look experienced, I am just trying to check everything because the issue looks kinda meaningless. When I tried myself, it just worked fine. I'm gonna upvote the question, hope somebody can help.

Comment: You can use manual device placement feature of Tensorflow to execute your code on GPU machine i.e., `tf.device('/GPU:0')`. For more details check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer I tried training within the `with tf.device('/GPU:0'):` block. It makes no difference. The computation uses CPU, while the GPU load remains at 0%.

Comment: Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` to confirm that TensorFlow is using the GPU.Thanks!